# Flutter [Get] the improper use of a GetX has been detected

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I got this error. I am encountering this error while checking if one after another. I'm not sure how the code I wrote works. I wanted to consult you about whether it works or not. Can anyone help with this problem and solve it?

```
return Obx(() => _languageController.isLang == ''
    ? LanguageView()
    : controller.getCurrentUser == null
        ? LoginView()
        : _countryController.isLanguage == false
            ? CountryView()
            : HomeView());

[Get] the improper use of a GetX has been detected. 
  You should only use GetX or Obx for the specific widget that will be updated.
  If you are seeing this error, you probably did not insert any observable variables into 
GetX/Obx 
  or insert them outside the scope that GetX considers suitable for an update 
  (example: GetX => HeavyWidget => variableObservable).
  If you need to update a parent widget and a child widget, wrap each one in an Obx/GetX.
```

Answer (score 2):

For the code above to work & not throw the error you saw, `isLang` must be an "observable".

For example, something like:

```
class LanguageController extends GetxController {
  RxBool isLang = false.obs();
}
```

Since the code in the question doesn't show `isLang`'s value being used (i.e. `isLang.value`), I'm guessing it's not an observable.

When using either `GetX` or `Obx` widgets, you must use "observables" (`RxBool`, `RxInt`, `Rx<Whatever>`, etc.).  A regular `int`, `bool`, etc. inside your controller is not enough to satisfy that requirement.  `GetX` and `Obx` require an observable type of `Rx` *something*.

Comment: Yes that's the bad part with GetX.  It mandates us to use observables ( even if we do not need them at scenarios)

Comment: @NikeshK `GetBuilder` is GetX's non-observable option for state-update widgets. (There are others, but this one is most common.)